# NSString stringWithFormat: for a number value

Tags: iphone, sdk, nsstring, nsxmlparser

Been working on this app for the past few days, and only finally just got the XML data parsed into a UITableView. But the main issue is the actual data parsed that's displayed on the table isn't how it should be displayed.

For example I've got one element (on XML file) that has a value of "134.9" (without the quotes), and if I use '[NSString stringWithFormat:@"£%@", [prices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];' it displays in the table as '{  Lowest = "134.9\n\t"; }'.

But if I use '%d' it comes up as a bunch of random numbers, that doesn't even match 134.9?

So here's the code:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"£%d", [prices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

This how the XML is setup:

```
<PetrolPrices>
<Fuel type="Unleaded">
<Highest units="p">145.9</Highest>
<Average units="p">135.2</Average>
<Lowest units="p">131.9</Lowest>
</Fuel>
<Fuel type="Diesel">
<Highest units="p">149.9</Highest>
<Average units="p">139.3</Average>
<Lowest units="p">135.9</Lowest>
</Fuel>
<Fuel type="LRP">
<Highest units="p">136.9</Highest>
<Average units="p">136.9</Average>
<Lowest units="p">136.9</Lowest>
</Fuel>
<Fuel type="Super Unleaded">
<Highest units="p">152.9</Highest>
<Average units="p">142.3</Average>
<Lowest units="p">135.9</Lowest>
</Fuel>
<Fuel type="LPG">
<Highest units="p">76.9</Highest>
<Average units="p">76.9</Average>
<Lowest units="p">76.9</Lowest>
</Fuel>
<Link>
</Link>
</PetrolPrices>
```

Lastly, the bit where I call it using the parser:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
{
    NSLog(@"ended element: %@", elementName);

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Fuel"])
    {
        [item setObject:fuel_price forKey:@"Lowest"];

        [item setObject:fuel_type forKey:@"type"];

        [prices addObject:[item copy]];

        NSLog(@"adding fuel prices: %@ - %@", fuel_price, fuel_type);
    }

}
```

Also if someone could tell me how I could get the attributes as well like for in the XML `<Fuel type="Unleaded">`, I can't seem to be able to retrieve this.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But if I use '%d' it comes up as a bunch of random numbers

%d is the format specifier for an int, but you're passing in an object. If you just want the number, keep the %d but pass in the correct value:

```
Item *item = [prices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"£%d", item.price];
```

or something along those lines, depending on your object.

Comment: Ah I know why it's doing the random numbers because it's including the 'Lowest = xxx.x ' as I mentioned I'm getting from the key 'Lowest', but on the XML it has 'unit="p"' if I called it from that would that solve it? The only thing is I don't know how to get the attributes..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html). This will make your coding easier.